# Tensorflow Object Detection Example: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'str'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working through the object detection example here: [Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md)

I have the data in the right places and the config file set up. I believe I am receiving error due to a version issue (but I am new to python).

Has anyone else worked through this example and come across this error?

I have the latest version of tensorflow, and I am using python 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue working to merge in [this PR](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/1593). Could you give it a try to see if it resolves your issue?

Comment: That is the problem. It does fix it. Thank you.